# jQuery Combine delegate statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code at 2 places of the same JS file;

```
$("#myGrid").delegate(".icon-right", "click", function() {
//Some code
});

$("#myGrid").delegate(".icon-down", "click", function() {
//Some code
});
```

So the diff is I am listening to click events on icon-down/icon-right

Is it possible to optimize / merge these 2 statements ?

Comment: You should use on-method instead atleast if you are not using very old jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Esa: Well, you should *consider* using the `on` method instead. The `delegate` method is still there in the latest versions, and it's not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both of them

```
$("#myGrid").delegate(".icon-right", "click", function () {
    //Some code
}).delegate(".icon-down", "click", function () {
    //Some code
});
```

---

Use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) after jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this:

```
$("#myGrid").delegate(".icon-right, .icon-down", "click", function () {
    if(this.className === 'icon-right'){ // some code}
    else if(this.className === 'icon-down'){ // some code}
});
```

---

If you are using jquery 1.7+ then you can try with `.on()` with `switch`:

```
$("#myGrid").on("click", ".icon-right, .icon-down", function () {
    switch(this.className){
       case 'icon-right':
          //some code
          break;
       case 'icon-down':
         // some code
         break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the selector match both:

```
$("#myGrid").delegate(".icon-right,.icon-down", "click", function() {
  //Some code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the multiple selector,

same function for all the elements:

```
$("#myGrid").delegate('click','.icon-right,.icon-down', function(e){ 
});
```

different functionality for different elements:

```
$("body").delegate('click','.icon-right,.icon-down', function(e){ 

    if      ($(this).is('.icon-right')) { }
    else                              { }

});
```